# Passing argument alias bash

Tags: bash, alias

Is it possible to do the following:

I want to run the following:

```
push 'foo'
```

I need execute:

```
git commit -m 'foo' && git push origin master && cap production deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a shell function instead of an alias:

```
push() {
    git commit -m "$1" && git push origin master && cap production deploy
}
```